# Move object with tween back and forth with Godot 4

Tags: godot, godot4

I had the following code inside an `all_tween_completed` signal:

```
func set_tween():
    if move_range == 0:
        return
    move_range *= -1
    var move_tween = get_tree().create_tween()
    move_tween.tween_property(self, "position:x",
                position.x + move_range,
                move_speed) \
                .from(position.x) \
                .set_trans(Tween.TRANS_QUAD) \
                .set_ease(Tween.EASE_IN_OUT)
```

So that after everything moved I swap sign and move to the other side. However, in Godot 4 there is no such signal. I already changed the code to accommodate for the new syntax but I am not sure how can I reproduce the previous behaviour. Do I need to keep calling and emitting the `finished` signal from Tween?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating an infinite loop of a two tween sequence? One tween from the start position to end position and the other from the end position to the start position.

Example Code:

```
var start_x := position.x
var end_x := position.x + move_range
var tween := create_tween().set_loops()
tween.tween_property(self, "position:x", end_x, move_speed).from(start_x)
tween.tween_property(self, "position:x", start_x, move_speed).from(end_x)
```